# Insert and update normalized tables in .net

Tags: .net, database, vb.net, ms-access-2010

You guys have been a great help for me with the inserting of data into table's and also where the ones pointing out that i can't use a single query to update or insert into multiple table's. So i'll need your help one more time. 
I'm writing software that can control a plc. However, the user has to be able to make rations that can be stored in a database for later use. 
To do so, i created 3 table's: tbl1, tbl2 and tbl3. First 2 are for the rations(foodtype, weight, location where it must go) and foods(type, storagelocation). the third table connects both tables using their ID as a FK.

Now, i can easily insert and update separate table's, but because a ration can exsist out of more than just 1 type of food, i need to be able to add more foods to one ration and update/insert this in the database using 1 button(for insert, 1 for update).

This is what i got sofar for inserting into the tables:

```
Dim Savestr As String
' Dim SaveStr1 As String
Dim Strkoppel As String
Savestr = "INSERT INTO tbl_rantsoen (Rantsoen, Voer, Gewicht) VALUES ('" & tbNieuwRantsoen.Text & "', '" & cbVoer.Text & "','" & tbGewicht.Text & "')"
'SaveStr1 = "INSERT INTO tbl_voersoorten ( Voer) VALUES ('" & cbVoer.Text & "')"
Strkoppel = "INSERT INTO tbl_rantsoenkoppel SELECT a.RantsoenID.  b.VoerID FROM tbl_rantsoen a INNER JOIN tbl_voersoorten b on b.Voer = a.Voer"
'Str2 = "INSERT INTO tbl_rantsoenKoppel (VoerID, RantsoenID) VALUES() WHERE RantsoenID = tbl_rantsoenkoppel.FKRantsoenID AND VoerID = tbl_voersoorten.VoerID"
connection.Open()
cmd = New OleDbCommand(Savestr, connection)
'cmd1 = New OleDbCommand(SaveStr1, connection)
cmd2 = New OleDbCommand(Strkoppel, connection)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
'cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

UPDATE:
I just had a brainfart, and even though this includes using a datagridvieuw(not preferable) it might work, if only i got the error's out(datatypes don't match in the expression)

Can anyone help me fixing that? Also, i know how to use 1 datagridviewrow to fill textboxes, i assume it works about the same when you use multiple records?

EDIT: Accidently got the datagridview working. :P Now i can populate the textboxes in the correct way. :) I am now stuck at the update/insert. Can anyone help me out? I got this error:

De opgegeven wijzigingen zijn niet aangebracht in de tabel omdat daardoor dubbele waarden ontstaan in de index, primaire sleutel of relatie. Wijzig de gegevens in het veld of de velden met dubbele gegevens, verwijder de index of definieer de index opnieuw zodat dubbele items zijn toegestaan. Probeer het vervolgens opnieuw.
In ENglish that would be something like "The changes hasnt been made in the table because it would create double values in the index, primary key or relation.

I'm using the following query's:

```
Savestr = "INSERT INTO tbl_rantsoen (Rantsoen, Voer, Gewicht, Locatie) VALUES ('" & tbNieuwRantsoen.Text & "', '" & cbVoer.Text & "','" & tbGewicht.Text & "', '" & cbLocatie.Text & "')"
SaveStr1 = "INSERT INTO tbl_voersoorten ( Voer) VALUES ('" & cbVoer.Text & "')"
Strkoppel = "INSERT INTO tbl_rantsoenkoppel SELECT tbl_rantsoen.RantsoenID, tbl_voersoorten.VoerID FROM tbl_rantsoen INNER JOIN tbl_voersoorten on tbl_rantsoen.Voer = tbl_voersoorten.Voer"
```

Question: How can i fix this? (if needed, i can upload my database.)

Did some changes to my database, now i get the error: De instructie INSERT INTO bevat de volgende onbekende veldnaam: RantsoenID. Controleer of u de naam correct hebt getypt en probeer het opnieuw. meaning that the INSERT INTO contains a unknown fieldname, even though that field does exist!
The Error is in cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery so it has to do with StrKoppel right? (StrKoppel is the string connecting the food table to the diet table) I think it's because i don't use the unique fields in both main tables, the only unique fields are the ID fields.

Comment: What's your question?  It's not clear from your post.

Comment: Sorry, Thought i had a question stated, but was wrong. I'm looking for a way to update and insert data in a normalized database. Can you guys help? I also need to pull that normalized data from the database so i can edit it or print a combination of data to .csv. (Ration, Food(multiple), weight(also multiple) location to get food from(different table, connected via the 3rd table) and some more data from the first table, some depending on data from the 3rd table(like weight(how many kg's of 1 food?)).

Comment: I still can't figure out what you are asking.  You say you're looking for a way to update and insert data in a normalized database."  That's UPDATE and INSERT INTO statements in SQL.  You say you need to "pull that normalized data from the database".  That's a SELECT statement in SQL.  Can you state, specifically, what the problem is that you are trying to solve and what you have tried?

Comment: @user3913708 - When you have additional info, please edit your question so everything is in one place as a single coherent story/question. You may leave a comment stating that you have edited your question to include the requested info.

Comment: Okay, got a bit further, though it still doesn´t work. Right now i can display different data from different tables in 1 form, but i still can´t select the correct corresponding data(or atleast, search for all foodtypes used for 1 diet), neither can i insert or update. HELP?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my best guess at what you need.

First, you need a "Rantsoen" table with two fields: RantsoenId and Name.  RantsoenId should be an Identity column so that Id values will be automatically generated when rows are inserted.  This table describes a ration, which may have one or more kinds of food in it.

Next, you want a FoodType ("Lebensmittel"?) table with two fields: FoodTypeId and Description.  Again, FoodTypeId should be an Identity column.

Finally. you want a Rantsoen_Food_Map table with two columns: RantsoenId and FoodTypeId.  This table describes which Rantsoens contain which food types.

You can then INNER JOIN these tables together to query the information that you need.

Comment: Those table's already exist. Other parts of the program are working fine(were i insert and read from 1 table) So that's not the problem. I got the table tbl_rantsoen with RantsoenID, Rantsoen, Voer, Gewicht and Locatie(where i. Then i have tbl_voersoorten with VoerID, Voer, Drogestof and Locatie, these 2 are connected through tbl_koppel using ID, FKVoerID and FKRantsoenID. What i need to get is the functionality to create and update new rations(Rantsoen) in 1 form, and then in a other form:

Comment: The ability to chose a ration, enter a number of persons and then let the program calculate the total weight per foodtype, show this data and save it to .csv 1 of the main things i'm wondering about is wether i need to use the koppel table(or Map table as you call it) or the 2 regular tables or all 3?

Comment: You need all three tables to know which food items are in which rations.  I'm not sure that I'm going to be able to be much more help.

Comment: Okay, well. Thanks anyway's! Anyone else got some advice?